# Why is permisson denied with n latest?

Tags: permissions, software-installation

I tried `n latest`

```
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/node': Permission denied
cp: cannot create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/npm': Permission denied
cp: cannot create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/npx': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/local/include/node': Permission denied
```

I already made folder

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/n && chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/n/
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

With sudo

```
sudo n latest
sudo: n: command not found
```

Comment: What's `n`? What does `type -a n` output? The `n` directory under `/usr/local` that you created seems unrelated to your issue (and that `chown` command should have failed unless you were already root, and would have done nothing if you were root).

Comment: https://github.com/tj/n.

Comment: n serves for Node.js installation.

Comment: The page you link says you need to take ownership of `/usr/local/*` if you're not going to install it under your own directory.  Seems dubious system admin to me, but those errors are expected if you haven't set up according to the instructions on that github page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/n && chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/n/
```

And

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/share
```

Answer (score 7):

This article outlines the issues you are running into as well as the PROPER way to fix it. You should always avoid running sudo where possible.

https://guillermo.at/update-node-proper-way

To update your npm:

```
npm i -g n
N_PREFIX=$HOME/.local n latest
```

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. To make it work forever export the value in your `.bashrc` or equivalent file: `export N_PREFIX=$HOME/.local`

Comment: This has changed the location for the npm